# Option Extrinsic value representation

Tags: options, black-scholes

The typical representation of the extrinsic value of an option is the following:
[image]

Is the gaussian the real representation of extrinsic value derived from Black and Scholes?
Should it be lognormal?

From an idea of quantpie I took the following graph:
[image]
It takes the lognormal of an underlying with an expected value of 10 (40% volatility and r=0) and divides the x-axis into intervals, every interval with its probability. The total summation of every single product gives 10, i.d. the expected value.
Then it chooses a strike K, at the money. The summation truncated at strike K is the N(d1)*S of BSM, the strike K multiplied by the same probability is the N(d2)*K of BSM, and the result is the option value, which can be defined as an "expected intrinsic value".
With the strike moving OTM the histograms decrease following a lognormal shaped tail.
What makes me think is that, from ATM to deep OTM, the extrinsic value of an option follows a lognormal, but from ATM to deep ITM what kind of distribution do we have?

P.s. I hope I made it clear, I'm from Italy and I write very seldom in English.

Comment: Assuming that by [extrinsic value](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/extrinsicvalue.asp#:~:text=Extrinsic%20value%20is%20the%20difference,in%20volatility%20in%20the%20market.) derived from Black and Scholes you mean the difference between the BS-price and the intrinsic value $(S-e^{-rt}K)^+$. This is neither normal nor lognormal. It may look similar to your graph though.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the normal is a good approximation

Comment: Have you tried how good that approximation is ? Looking roughly similar is all I get.

Comment: There is a square in the normal and none in @KurtG. formula, I say they are quite different.

Comment: @GiovanniBerardi . I voted to close the question. Because we have an explicit formula for extrinsic value in the BSM case I fail to see why we need to approximate it by some PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the BSM call price is well-known, hence, the exact formula for the "extrinsic value" (more commonly called time-value) $\text{EV}$ is well known:
$$
\text{EV}=SN(d_1)-e^{-rt}KN(d_2)-(S-e^{-rt}K)^+\quad\text{ where }\quad d_{1,2}=\frac{\log(S/K)+rt\pm\sigma^2t/2}{\sigma\sqrt{t}}\,.
$$
With $K=10,r=0,t=1,\sigma=40\%$ I fitted a normal and a lognormal density to the extrinsic value $\text{EV}$ to the best of my ability (the $x$-axis is the spot price $S$):

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 It is clear from these graphs that the curve *is quite different* from the normal and log-normal distributions.

Comment: @Kurt G. Thank you very much